# few doubts about Android Framebuffer

Tags: android, framebuffer

I have few doubts about the Android Framebuffer,

1. Is it same as Linux Framebuffer ?
2. where do we allocate the two buffer(for double buffering) exactly (code wise also)? How MDP know which buffer it needs to use to get the frame data ?
3. How MDP signals that he has taken the data from framebuffer, and is ready to take new data?

Apart from these also I have few doubts specific to functions used in surfaceflinger, but that I can ask later if the above question is answered.

Comment: What is Android Framebuffer?

Comment: what I meant with Android Framebuffer, was the framebuffer we used in Android platform code.